# Help with modular arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic

If$r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4,\ldots,r_{ϕ(a)}$ are the distinct positive integers less than $a$ and coprime to $a$, is there some way to easily calculate, $$\prod_{k=1}^{\phi(a)}ord_{a}(r_k)$$

Comment: Every integer $n$ coprime to $a$ is congruent to one of the $r_i$, so you don't need anything remotely close to the product you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  claim is true, with the stronger condition that there is some $i$ with $e_i=1$ and all other exponents are zero.  The set of $r_i$'s is called a [reduced residue system](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReducedResidueSystem.html).

The second (now deleted) claim is false.  Let $a=7$.  Then $2^13^1=6^1$, two different representations.